# How to include plots / rows with zero values in the presence / absence community matrix in a CCA using R Vegan package

Tags: r, statistics, vegan

I am trying to do CCA using a presence / absence matrix of plant quadrat data and continuous environmental data for the same quadrats, using the Vegan package in R. Some of the quadrats have no plant species present (the row for the quadrat is full of 0's) but do have corresponding environmental data in another dataframe. The context of the study is that the environmental data is metal concentrations in soil, which are typically high where there are no plant species, so the quadrats with zero species do contribute to the data, and are not errors or NA's. When running the CCA with the R Vegan Package so far I have had to delete these rows to get it to work, otherwise it returns the error
'Error in cca.default(d$X, d$Y, d$Z) :
all row sums must be >0 in the community data matrix' .
Is there a way to include the data from quadrats that have no plant species in the CCA? I have read in this paper, which also uses the Vegan package,: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229087061_Relationships_between_the_presence_of_odonate_species_and_environmental_characteristics_in_lowland_ponds_of_central_Italy and that has a similar research design, that they have included plots with zero species by adding a 'zero species' variable but do not elaborate on how this is done.
I am new to coding so any help is very much appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: By the looks of that paper, they just added an extra binary column, "zero_species", to the site/species matrix, and coded a 1 if there were no other species. I'm not sure if that's a valid approach

Comment: There is no way to include zero species to CCA. CCA is based on composition, and zero has no composition (and 0/0 is not a number).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it. Assume your data set is called `comm` and it has some rows (sampling units) that have no species:

```
comm$ZERO <- as.numeric(rowSums(comm) == 0)
```

This will add a new column `ZERO` which is 1 for rows that had no species, and 0 for others.

Personally, I would be worried about doing this. Correspondence Analysis is a compositional analysis, and adding a column (species) that never occurs with any other species (by definition) creates a data set with two disjunct blocks. In unconstrained CA this disjunct block manifests in first eigenvalue 1 – which is the theoretical maximum in CA. This first eigenvector will separate the blocks: ZERO species and the sampling units with ZERO species in one extreme, and all other species and sampling units in another extreme of the first axis. The second axis of this ZERO ordination will be identical to the first axis without ZERO, so in effect you just add this disjunction axis to the ordination.

Things are slightly different with CCA which actually looks at the *fitted* values of your species, and these fitted values may not be disjunct. So technically you can do it. However, it is not quite clear to me what you do if you do so. Even if the data set is not completely disjunct with CCA, the zero sampling units will probably be far separated from other points, and all plotted in the same point.